# How to run a jar file(Which has selenium automation, webdirver) in a different PC

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have been playing around with selenium IDE and webdriver. 
I wrote a small java program in eclipse which starts the Mozilla browser and goes to Google and searches for a keyword infinite times. This program works in my PC(windows 7, JDK - 1.8_40), but when i created an executable file and tried it in my laptop(Windows 8.1) where it opens the browser, but nothing shows up in the page screen.

The executable jar ran in my PC where i created the jar file. 
Following is the code:

```
package Test1;


import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        String appURL =  "http://www.google.com";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(appURL); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 1;)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("selenium");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("this is a test");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the FireFox driver (which is basicly a proxy-tool for interacting with it using Selenium) is not covering your Firefox version. So the question is - which version of firefox driver and Firefox by itself do you have?

Comment: Thank you, i updated the Firefox driver and it is working now. Forgot about checking the versions.